# Optimizing TouchableOpacity for Faster and Smoother Touch Response in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, mobile

I want to create a React Native project featuring a component that returns a selectable week calendar. In this component, I aim to create a touchable element for each date (using TouchableOpacity) that becomes selected when clicked.

```
import { addDays, format, getDate, isSameDay, startOfWeek } from 'date-fns';
import { te } from 'date-fns/locale';
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView,StyleSheet, View,Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';





type Props = {
    date: Date;
    onChange: (vale: Date) => void;
}

const WeekCalendar: React.FC<Props> = ({date, onChange}) =>{
    const [week,setWeek] = useState<WeekDay[]>([]);
    

    useEffect (() =>{
        const weekDays = getWeekDays(date);
        setWeek(weekDays);
    }, [date]);


    return (
        <>
        <View style={styles.container}>
        {week.map(weekDay => {
            const textStyles = [styles.label];
            const touchable = [styles.touchable];
            const sameDay = isSameDay(weekDay.date,date);

            if(sameDay){
                textStyles.push(styles.selectedLabel);
                touchable.push(styles.selectedTouchable);
            }
            return (<View style={styles.weekDayItem} key={weekDay.formatted}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onChange(weekDay.date)} style={touchable}>
                    <View style={styles.dayContainer}>
                      <Text style={styles.weekDayText}>
                        {weekDay.formatted} 
                      </Text>
                      <Text style={textStyles}>                          
                          {weekDay.day}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>);
        })}    
        
        </View>
        
        </>
    );
};

/*
*/ 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  dayContainer:{
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent : 'space-around',
        paddingVertical: 10,
        //backgroundColor:'#EDE6DB',
        //borderColor: 'black',
        //borderWidth: 1,
        //padding: 5,
        //borderRadius: 10,
    },
    weekDayText: {
        color : 'gray',        
        fontSize: 11,
    },
    label:{
        fontSize: 20,
        color: 'black',
        textAlign:'center',
        
    },
    selectedLabel:{
        color:'white',
    },
    touchable: {
        borderRadius: 20,
        padding: 3,
        height: 60,
        width:45,
        
    },
    selectedTouchable:{
        backgroundColor:'#417D7A',
    },
    weekDayItem:{
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
});

type WeekDay ={
    formatted : string;
    date: Date;
    day: number;
}

export const getWeekDays = (date: Date):WeekDay[] => {
    const start = startOfWeek(date, {weekStartsOn: 1} );
  
    const final = [];
  
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      const date = addDays(start, i);
      final.push({
        formatted: format(date, 'EEE'),
        date,
        day: getDate(date),
      });
    }
  
    return final;
  };

  

export default WeekCalendar;
```

The issue I'm facing is that the TouchableOpacity's click response is slow and inefficient. How can I improve this?